# Javascript timer calls a Code behind method only once

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, timer, heatmap

I've am trying to create a dynamic heatmap by calling code behind methodw that supplies the data to the heatmap. I have a timer that calls the function **GetNewHeatMapDataTable()**. The function fetches new data and pushes it to an existing array (pointArray) to dynamaically update the map. The timer runs as expecte. However, the value of the variable **newheatmapdata** does not change and the function only calls the code behind method **GetIAHeatMapDataTable("XXXXXXX")** only once. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Below is a snippet of my code

```
var heatmapData = [];
function GetDataTableFromCodeBehind() {

        heatmapData = <%=GetIAHeatMapDataTable("XXXXXXX")%>;                        
    }        


var pointArray = new google.maps.MVCArray(heatmapData);
    var heatmapLayer = new google.maps.visualization.HeatmapLayer({ 
        data: pointArray, 
        dissipating: false,
        radius: 0.00001
    }); 

function GetNewHeatMapDataTable() {             
        var newheatmapdata = []   
        newheatmapdata = <%=GetIANewHeatMapDataTable("XXXXXXX")%>;               

        if (newheatmapdata.length > 0){

            for (i = 0; i < newheatmapdata.length; i++) {
                pointArray.push.apply(pointArray, newheatmapdata);                    
            }
        }                                 
    }   
setInterval(function() {GetNewHeatMapDataTable();},3000);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You cannot call a server method like that from the client,you need to make an AJAX call to the server. The javascript is not aware of the server side method, all you do with the current code is call the method once while generating the page.

Comment: Are you seeing different value of this GetIANewHeatMapDataTable("XXXXXXX")

Comment: Hi user2181397,

I am not seeing different values. I am able to call the method and successfully get data array only once. However once timer hits the interval, the method  GetIANewHeatMapDataTable("XXXXXXX") is not called anymore and initial value of variable  newheatmapdata does not change

Comment: Thank you Stephen, I will try your suggestion

Comment: SOLVED: Thank you very much Stephen. I did just as you suggested. Worked like a charm

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: Thank you very much Stephen. I did just as you suggested. Worked like a charm. This is my new code for fetching new data and pushing it to the heatmap

```
    function fetchNewData() {    
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "Webform1.aspx/GetIANewHeatMapDataTable",
                data: JSON.stringify({ level: "XXXXXXX" }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function(data) {                     
                    var newheatmapdata = [] ;
                    newheatmapdata = eval('(' + data.d + ')');

                    if (newheatmapdata.length > 0){    
                        for (i = 0; i < newheatmapdata.length; i++) {                                
                            pointArray.push.apply(pointArray, newheatmapdata);                                    
                            heatmapLayer.setData(pointArray);
                        }
                    }                            
                },
            });

        }
    setInterval(function() {fetchNewData();},1000);
```